# Why isn't this web storage code working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, storage

I'm pretty new to coding. I taught myself a good amount of Javascript using Codecademy.com. I'm trying to expand my horizons and make a simple save game code. The user would click a button, and each click adds +1 to their score. I want to make it so that if the user leaves the browser, he or she can go right back and see their score from before. Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('clicks', 0);
    $('#total-clicks').text(Number(localStorage.clicks));

    $('.click-here').click(function() {
        localStorage.clicks = Number(localStorage.clicks) + 1;
        $('#total-clicks').text(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
    });
});
```

It seems like I am doing it right, but it's not working. Let me know how I can fix this and/or what I am doing wrong. I'm not 100% sure how web storage works, If anyone has any good references to help me, please let me know as well. Thanks.

Comment: Well on every page load you will be overriding it....

Comment: You need to check if the value is there already, only set it to zero if it's not there

Comment: Create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the question for the ease of understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're initializing it to `0` everytime you load.

So you check to see if it's first set, if not... then set it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!localStorage.clicks) {
        localStorage.setItem('clicks', 0);
    }
    $('#total-clicks').text(Number(localStorage.clicks));
    $('.click-here').click(function () {
        console.log('+1!');
        localStorage.clicks = Number(localStorage.clicks) + 1;
        $('#total-clicks').text(localStorage.getItem('clicks'));
    });

});
```

## [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bTL58/1/)

Comment: some browsers not support localStorage or sessionStorage, recommend use cookie

Answer (score 1):

You override it on every load. Check for a value before you set it.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("clicks") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('clicks', 0);
}
```